# Downloading an entire webpage with C: recv()

Tags: c, sockets, recv

Good evening.

I'm trying to obtain the full contents of webpages (images excepted) through a C application.

After connecting to the desired URL, I use recv(), like so:

```
char *reply;
reply==malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
recv(socketname, reply, 10000, 0);
```

This gives me a part of the page (958-972 bytes, according to recv()'s return value).

So, I tried modifying it to:

```
ssize_t received=0;
char *reply, *buffer;
reply=malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
buffer=malloc(255*sizeof(char));
while(received<10000) {
     received+=recv(socketname, buffer, 10000, 0);
     strcat(reply, buffer);
}
```

But this gives me a segmentation fault on large pages (before exceeding the size allocated to the reply) and, on small pages, results in the reply containing several times the contents of the page.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: `recv()` does not NUL terminate what it reads, since the data coming in may not be a string. `strcat()` is not the right solution.

Comment: You use a common library for HTTP, rather than trying to do a one-off implementation yourself.

Comment: Novelocrat: could you please direct me towards that library?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: After connecting, you cannot just `recv` a web page. First you have to send a `get` command, like `GET example.com/index.html  HTTP/1.0`.

Comment: Yes, I do send a GET. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer=malloc(255*sizeof(char));` gives you only 255 bytes.

`recv(socketname, buffer, 10000, 0);` tries to read much more.

That's why you get a segfault.

Also, you do not know what you actualy download, so you'd be better off with `memcpy` to copy.

An untested example:

```
ssize_t received=0, current_received=0;
char *reply, *buffer;
reply=malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
buffer=malloc(255*sizeof(char));
while(received<10000) {
     current_received = recv(socketname, buffer, 255, 0);
     if(current_received <= 0) {
         //if we're done or we have an error. Think about some error handling.
         break;
     }
     //I have switched the following lines to make it a bit easier.
     //As an exercise try to avoid overflow if received=9999 and current_received=255 :)
     memcpy(reply + received, buffer, current_received);
     received += current_received;
}
```

If you're looking for a library that will do it for you, check [this link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html).

Keep in mind that using a library might be actually quite difficult if you want just a very simple example.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have 2 #defines for 255 & 10000 and I'd mixed them up.
Using the right one indeed lifts the segfault. I'll use memcopy() as well.

I still receive several times the content of the page for small pages, though.

Comment: @MalcolmTucker I'm glad I could help - if you like my answer you can accept it with this tick sign ;-) As for the `memcpy` I'll give you an example of what I have in mind, in a second.

Comment: As far as avoiding overflow, I'm just using a do... while(). And I was already handling recv() errors, I just didn't include it for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

But to jxh's point, you want to be using `memcpy` instead of `strcat`, and keeping any advancing pointer into your consolidated reply, incrementing by `received` each time.